Diagnosing large usage on WSL volume
I am new to Ubuntu, I just use it through WSL to run Docker. I found that there is around 40GB being used and I'm trying to find out why.
I have run the following commands
df -ah
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sdc        251G   39G  200G  17% /
...

du -sh -x
du: cannot read directory '/wsllNePbo': Permission denied
... lots of similar directories like this
du: cannot read directory '/etc/polkit-1/localauthority': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/etc...
du: cannot read directory '/opt/containerd': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/root': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/tmp/tmpg4wh8wug': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/var/spool/cron/atjobs': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/var/spool/cron/crontabs': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/var/spool/cron/atspool': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/var/spool/rsyslog': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/var/lib/docker': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/var/lib/polkit-1': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/var/lib/apt/lists/partial': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/var/lib/private': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/var/lib/postgresql/12/main': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/var/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloads/partial': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/var/lib/redis': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/var/lib/snapd/void': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/var/cache/apt/archives/partial': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/var/cache/ldconfig': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/var/cache/private': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/var/log/private': Permission denied
du: cannot read directory '/lost+found': Permission denied

3.7G    /

After all of the 'permission denied' messages I ran the same command with sudo and just got
39G     /

and nothing else.
How do I diagnose what is taking up the space and how do I clear it?

You might want to try some of the suggestions here: No more disk space: How can I find what is taking up the space?
